# Alternative to declaring const in google sheets script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, constants

I understand that google sheets does not support `const` declaration

I currently use var at the global level. This of course allows duplicate declarations of the same name to take place.
One may define the following global statements in two different scripts files, within the same project.

```
var name = "Jhon";
var name = "Sam";
```

Only the last to be loaded will be actually take place.

What is the best practice to avoid that, if any at all?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Apps Script does not support constants (they where released in [ECMA6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_-_ECMAScript_2015)), as it is mostly based on [Javascript 1.6](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features) (or [ECMA4](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.6)) with a few features of 1.7 and 1.8.

However, there is a feature request on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36764074) asking for those features to be implemented. You can click on the star next to the issue number to give more priority to the request and to receive updates. There are plans to implement it but there is no specific release date yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can [upgrade to the modern faster V8 engine](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime) to use `const`

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems with variables colliding because they defined globally, you can try encapsulating your code inside an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

As functions create new scopes, the variables used inside an IIFE can only be accessed inside it.

For example, you could end up with a file like:

```
(function() {
    var globalVarInsideFunction = 'value';

    function myPrivateFunc() {
        // Here you can use globalVarInsideFunction.
    }
})();
```

Comment: Didnt know IIFE. I'v been reading a bit about that. I guess what you are suggesting is to encapsulate each script in its own (...here is the script with many functions...). The "self excracting" part, i.e the ending parenthesis like in the example below is irrelevant here. isnt it? `(function myFunc() {
  Logger.log("Hi");
}) () ;`

Comment: Yes! That's exactly it! In this way, everything that's inside `myFunc` will be private.

Comment: Not sure I undesrtand. Please see my additional post.

Comment: @OJNSim, I added an example code so you can see better what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using sheets and I use const normally. In below example if you removed the comment from the line `//a = 6;` There will be an error:

> TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
> myFunction  @ scripts.js.gs:3

Meanwhile the `var b` can be reassigned freely.

Code:

```
function myFunction() {
  const a = 5;
  //a = 6;

  var b = 5;
  b = 6
  Logger.log("a = "+a+", b = "+b);
}
```